# Rails give Value to a string field by pressing specific icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, drop-down-menu, icons

I'm a bit new to rails..

I currently have a drop down feature on my rails app showing the specified options (6 different selections in my app). Is there any way to create 6 separate icons or buttons so that if you press one it will set the value of the string field type to a specified value designated to that button or icon?

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely possible. You may want to be more specific though, because there are many ways to accomplish this. One way would be create a form for each option with a hidden field containing the value you want to update and make the icon/button the submit for that form.

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, I understand you're trying to replace the select_tag (which has 6 different options) with 6 different buttons.
In that case, you just need some jQuery like this associated to each button

```
$("#text_field_id").val("The Value");
```